# How to get default system font for specific language on Android?

Tags: android, fonts

Is it possible to get a system font on Android that has all the symbols of the language that the device is currently running on?

For example, if I am running Turkish language, I would like to get a system font that has all the Turkish symbols in it. Is it possible to achieve this somehow?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? From what I know strings.xml is used to store values. I don't see how it would help me to get system font.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: I'm sorry this is not what I'm looking for. What I need is to actually render the strings using some sort of a font. The problem is that one font has Turkish symbols, but doesn't have Japanese symbols. I want to get some sort of a font that would contain all the symbols for specific language, I don't really care what the font looks like.